# powerdot in TeXstudio

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to create a powerdot presentation in TeX studio, but it executes with error that I don't understand how to fix. In MiKTex Manager powerdot package is installed.

```
Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',(hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode. \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

and I am trying to run these lines:

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{Powerdot Presentation}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an explanation and a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Powerdot uses PSTricks, so a Powerdot presentation cannot be compiled with pdflatex (that I know). Maybe that's the issue?